# how to create cache object when site is loaded at first time in browser in asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

it is creating when the page is loading in browser and the object values are clearing the when the page is loading,

i need to retrieve and assign the values only not any empty strings

```
       if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Cache["userid"] = string.Empty;
            Cache["password"] = string.Empty;    
        }
```

Comment: Ravisankar Cache is application level "mechanism" it is used by all app request. So you can't store userId in Cache. I think HttpContext.Session is more sutable for your needs.

Comment: thanks but i need with cache only why bcz sessions are server side state management it is hitting to server for each and every session.